# Is it possible to upgrade Lenovo L412 stock display to one with an higher native resolution?

Tags: display, lenovo-laptop, lcd

I am trying to find a way to upgrade my old but still good Lenovo L412 with its 1366x768 display. After researching a while I found some compatible 14 inch panels with 40 pins lvds interface on panelook.com and I bought this ltn140kt01 with a native resolution of 1600x900 px. The screen has been recognizer by both windows and Linux os but in both cases the image was very blurry. What can be the issue for that? I am suspecting on the 40pin LVDS cable, but after some other research it's not clear to me how many of these do exist and which one should I buy. Additionally, the original LVDS cable also transports the signal for the integrated webcam and it would be nice to make it work again after the upgrade. Is the issue on the cable which cannot supply a sufficient bandwidth or is the upgrade of this Lcd impossible?

Comment: Strange. All the 1600x900 displays I have seen for your model were 40-pin. Only 1366x768 ones were 30-pins. I hesitate to suggest that you bought a fake.

Comment: You're right. Both stock (B140XW01 V7) and replacement candidate are 40pin LVDS monitor. I edited the original question accordingly.

Comment: This question is largely above my head, but could this be as simple as as a software (driver) resolution setting?

Comment: I don't think so. The display has been recognised from the PC and the native resolution (1600x900@60) has correctly been selected from the system. Image on the screen were correctly displayed, the only thing it was that they were very blurry and not acceptable to be used. Unfortunately I already return the item back to avoid loosing my money and I didn't take any picture of this :(

Comment: Can this issue be resolved using a different LVDS cable? I'm not very into the lvds standard but I read that different lvds cables exist, though I don't really know the differences between these.